# How do I use a file path variable to save an image file?

Tags: python

I have the variable `myfile`:

```
>>> print(myfile)
/Users/mnewman/pyweb/py.jpg
```

I try to use it here, but it doesn't work. No image is saved at that location:

```
>>> os.popen("imagesnap -d 'HD Webcam C615 #2' myfile").read()
'Capturing image from device "<AVCaptureDALDevice: 0x7fc618d2f910 [HD Webcam C615 #2][0x14220000046d082c]>"...'
```

But this works:

```
>>> os.popen("imagesnap -d 'HD Webcam C615 #2' /Users/mnewman/pyweb/py.jpg").read()
'Capturing image from device "<AVCaptureDALDevice: 0x7ffe7b5300e0 [HD Webcam C615 #2][0x14220000046d082c]>"...'
```

How should I use the file path variable?

Comment: Did you mean: os.popen(f”imagesnap -d 'HD Webcam C615 #2' {myfile}").read() ?

Comment: On the other hand, in this line: ftpr=ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {os.path.split(myfile)[1]}', open(myfile, 'rb')) - I use just the variable name to refer to the file path and it works. But it didn't work in the other line of code. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add it to the string, you have to do `string concatenation`.  Like this:

```py
>>> os.popen("imagesnap -d 'HD Webcam C615 #2' "+myfile).read()
'Capturing image from device "<AVCaptureDALDevice: 0x7fc618d2f910 [HD Webcam C615 #2][0x14220000046d082c]>"...'
```

Notice the `+` (plus)?  That put the string together and made them one.  Before, you had that the word `myfile` was a word in the string, not a string attached to a string.

If this answered your question, click the gray check mark on the left to accept this answer as the right one.

Comment: I copied you line (beginning os.popen) but got this error: `Device "HD Webcam C615 #2/Users/mnewman/pyweb/py.jpg" not found.`

Comment: @Buadhai : All you need to do is add a space after the `'` character in the string.  String concatenation doesn't care about adding spaces, so you need to add them manually.  the new string would be: `"imagesnap -d 'HD Webcam C615 #2' "+myfile`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Keep in my that I just started to learn Python last week, so I'm still somewhat unsure about how things work; including the significance of spaces. I originally just copied and pasted what you posted not realizing that the missing space would cause it to fail.

Comment: @Buadhai : You're welcome.  I hope that whatever you are building will work this time! 

Comment: At the moment I'm just trying to learn. My project is to rewrite one of my old bash shell scripts in Python. It's turning out to be a lot harder than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

The first example doesn't work because you're using the literal filename `myfile`.

If you're using Python 3.6 or newer (which you should), then you can use F-strings which are a convenient way to integrate variable values into strings.

Try this:

```
os.popen(f"imagesnap -d 'HD Webcam C615 #2' {myfile}").read()
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't quite understand F-strings or how to use them. Now I do.

Answer (score 0):

`myfile` in your string are just the characters and has nothing to do with any variable of that name.

You should use `subprocess` instead of `os.popen` and use a list of arguments:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["imagesnap", "-d", "HD Webcam C615 #2", myfile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.stdout.read()
process.wait()
```

Comment: I tried this, but got this error: NameError: `name 'subprocess' is not defined`. I don't know what that means or how to fix it. If I need to import something else, I have no way of knowing what that might be.